# Controlling how UltraVNC handles Alt + Tab

Tags: windows, alt-tab, ultravnc

Most of the time UltraVNC ignores <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and I am able to switch away from UltraVNC to another application. I like this behavior.

However, occasionally it gets into a mode where - for no discernible reason - it passes the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to the remote host which is incredibly annoying as I am used to the other behavior and suddenly I have no keyboard shortcut to switch to a different local windows. Since it appears to exhibit both behaviors, I assume there is some way to control which behavior is in use, but I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting Windows causes UltraVNC to revert to the default of not passing Alt+Tab to the remote.

Answer (score 17):

The <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> key affects this.
If scroll lock is on, the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is sent to the remote computer.
If it's off, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is handled locally by the client.

Comment: This might be true for UltraVNC, but it has no effect for TightVNC 2.7.10 (TightVNC for both client and server).

Comment: *[UltraVNC Viewer Usage](http://www.uvnc.com/docs/uvnc-viewer.html)*, section "Additional Hotkeys", supports the claim about Scroll Lock. But is it still valid for contemporary versions?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yup, a recent (1.2.2.4 built in March 2019) version still works as advertized in this answer.

Comment: This is still true. On my Thinkpad P51s that doesn't have a physical scroll lock key, the functionality is `Fn + K`